# save the user name in session from the login page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can I ask you guys here, how to create session from login page? I want to make an edit page which user can view only their data in the gridview so they need to call the username session in order to retrieve only their records in db. If you guys have any doubts regarding to my question, pls ask me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just use the user reference in `HttpContext.Current.User`?  You can use this to pass to your data retrieval code for your gridview.

If you are using the Membership API, then try something like this:

```
MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
string currentUserName = currentUser.UserName;

// pass currentUserName to your data access
```

Or

```
string currentUserName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: I just dont know how to do that.

Comment: do you have fb or skype? Can we chat?

Comment: @dontshare The point of SO is to have a working solution for each question so that it can be referenced at later times.  In other words, let's work through this problem here so others can use it in the future.  What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to save the username to the session and retrieve it later:

```
//set
Session["username"] = value;
//get
string username = (string)Session["username"];
```

As I think, using session is asking for trouble. So if you are looking for a better solution refer the @Shark's solution